# Jersey API Cache

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Estou com dúvidas em relação ao controle de Cache do Jersey. Utilizando QueryParam, corre o risco do navegardor/servidor realizar o cache do resultado? Ou isso acontece apenas quando trabalho com PathParam dentro do meu método GET?